# Подскажите плиз как программно открыть определенный каталог в Андроид 10?

Tags: java, android

мне нужно чтобы после нажатия на мою кнопку запускался диспетчер файлов смартфона и отображал содержимое определенного каталога, например Android/data.

Comment: EXTRA_INITIAL_URI https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract#EXTRA_INITIAL_URI

Comment: @style-7 попробовал разные варианты, упорно открывается папка Downloads 
  String path=Environment.getDataDirectory().toString(); intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, path);